# How to match two attributes within the same object in elastic search Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hey everyone so let's assume I have the following data structured in the following format in elastic search:

```
"dataset1" :
{
"listoftasks": [ 
 {
   "task" : {
      "id": 1351
   },
   "statusOfTask": "completed"
 },
 {
   "task" : {
      "id": 1355
   },
   "statusOfTask": "completed"
 },
 {
   "task" : {
      "id": 1350
   },
   "statusOfTask": "incomplete"
 }
]
},
"dataset2" :
{
"listoftasks": [ 
 {
   "task" : {
      "id": 1351
   },
   "statusOfTask": "incomplete"
 },
 {
   "task" : {
      "id": 1355
   },
   "statusOfTask": "completed"
 },
 {
   "task" : {
      "id": 1350
   },
   "statusOfTask": "incomplete"
 }
]
}
```

Like dataset1 and dataset2, there are numerous other datasets likewise. I want to write an ES query to retrieve all data sets in which there's a taskid of 1351 and a corresponding statusOfTask of completed. I have the following query below currently.

```
"query":{
          "nested": {
            "path": "xxx",
            "query": {
              "bool":{
                "must":[
                  { "match": {"listoftasks.statusOfTask": "completed"}},
                  { "match": {"listoftasks.task.id": "1351"}}
                ]
              }
            }
          }
  }
```

However, this query is returning dataset1 and dataset2 when it should only be returning dataset1. My guess is that since there exists a taskid of 1351 and a statusOfTask of completed within dataset2, its returning dataset2. so how would i change the query to make it check the corresponding statusOfTask inside the same object of the taskid of 1351??

Comment: please, provide the mapping and documents to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

Without the mapping, it is difficult to see what will happen, but I am assuming you have listoftasks of type nested. The problem is most likely that your id field is a deeper sub property. If you had the fields as
"taskid" : 1351,
"statusOfTask": "incomplete"

then it would probably work.

Comment: yea but i cant modify the underlying data, is there no solution then?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, if you can't underline the data try to use `script query` in your Elasticsearch query to filer as following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "listoftasks",
            "query": {
              "script": {
                "script": """
                  for (task in doc['listoftasks.task.id']) {
                    if (task == 1351) {
                      int index = doc['listoftasks.task.id'].indexOf(task);
                      if (doc['listoftasks.statusOfTask'][index].value != 'completed') {
                        return false;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  return true;
                """
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do u know the correct syntax for the code. I keep coming across compiler issues. ive tried changing it based on what ive seen online too.

Comment: What compile issues are you seeing?